# “Cool car” and “hot car” in the context of a robbery

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie

Context is bank robbery.
The gang set up a system with two cars : first car is a hot car, usually stolen, used for the robbery. The second car, the cool car, is the one parked not too far from the place of robbery, which the gang switches to.

I can decide to use the "hot" and "cool" in translation, explaining it. Unless there is an equivalent in French bank heist business…

Comment: Are these commonly used expressions in English? Besides in the specific settings of a specif heist, it doesn't look like it could mean much...

Comment: If by "hot car" you mean a car used to **break through** the bank, a French word could be ***voiture-bélier*** (more often used to break through jewelries)

Comment: No. Voiture-bélier is in case of heist with violent smashing of window. Case described in my first post is the opposite : escape-car.

Comment: I would use propre / clean and sale / dirty, but there's not that much idiom like that in French it's a very English way to build new term by aggregating non related term.

Answer (score 2):

It don't think there is an official term for this in french, especially with this opposed meaning pair scheme. So you could fallback on a word game, but with a slighlty different meaning : i.e.: "voiture casse" (a heist car) and "voiture classe" (a classy car, meaning it looks OK and doesn't raises suspicion, Im' not so sure on this one, but you get the logic ^^)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if terms like this already exists, but here's an idea. You could say "*voiture leurre*" (the "red herring car") for the hot car, and "*voiture de secours*" (backup car) for the cool car. This way I think it's clear that the first car is only used to attract attention to it, while the second car is used to actually get away.